# How to loop through all html elements that contain a certain class name in TMS WEB Core?

Tags: javascript, delphi, tms, tms-web-core, delphi-12-athens

I have a couple of HTML elements on my page that were created dynamically, so my Delphi form doesn't know about them (as far as I'm aware), but all of them have a class attribute called "TestingClass" on the HTML Element. Here's one of them as an example:

```
<div class="TestingClass">
...
</div>
```

I'm able to loop through all of them using JavaScript code within Delphi from my form such as:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Testing(Sender: TObject);
begin
  asm
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".TestingClass");
    elements.forEach((element) => {
        console.log(element);
        // Access each element using the "element" parameter
    });
  end;
end;
```

And that works, but ideally, I'd like to eliminate the JavaScript code and use only Delphi. What would be the equivalent Delphi code to get all elements on my page with that class and then loop through it?

Note that all of these HTML elements are created dynamically using JavaScript. So they don't have the form or application as the owner, but they're all definitely visible on the page and in the DOM.

Comment: You could point out that you talk about [CSS classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS#Selector_types), or a [HTML element's `class=` attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_attribute#Common_attributes). Otherwise this will surely confuse OOProgrammers in general.

Comment: @AmigoJack Thanks. I've updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I managed to figure it out.

If you have the `WEB` unit in your uses, then you can access the `document` variable and use the following two ways to do it:

## Using `document.querySelectorAll`

```
procedure TfrmMain.Testing(Sender: TObject);
var
  TestingClass: TJSNodeList;
  I: UInt64;
begin
  TestingClass := document.querySelectorAll('.TestingClass');
  for I := 0 to TestingClass.length-1 do
  begin
    console.log(TestingClass.item(I));
    // Access each element using "TestingClass.item(I)"
  end;
end;
```

## Using `document.getElementsByClassName`

```
procedure TfrmMain.Testing(Sender: TObject);
var
  TestingClass: TJSHTMLCollection;
  I: UInt64;
begin
  TestingClass := document.getElementsByClassName('TestingClass');
  for I := 0 to TestingClass.length-1 do
  begin
    console.log(TestingClass.Items[I]);
    // Access each element using "TestingClass.Items[I]"
  end;
end;
```